# Response codes from Java.net.Url conection - Rest Webservice Client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I am using Java.Net.URL for making a Rest webservice call.

using the below example code.

```
URL url = new URL("UrlToConnect");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();
```

i am trying to capture response code from this webservice call. I observed that Even after putting a wrong URL i am getting 200 response code from the connection. Please suggest a way by which i can capture response codes 200 , 201 and 202.

Thanks.